# Quotes inside quotes inside quotes inside quotes ( 4 levels )

Tags: javascript, regex, quotes

```
$(document.getElementById(id)).replaceWith("<tr onclick='$( document.getElementById(\"" + id + "\")).replaceWith(\"<tr onclick=&#39;editMessage(<quotehere>"+ id +"<quotehere>)&#39; id=&#39;" + id + "&#39;>" + replace + "</tr>\")' id='" + id + "'>...";
```

In upper code where I call editMessage function id needs to be enclosed in another quote but I'm counting total of 4 levels of quotes and highest level examples are level 3.

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: **Code improvement:** If you are using jquery, then you don't need to write `$(document.getElementById(id))`. You can simply use this: `$("#" + id)`.

Comment: I can't use that because my id contains invalid character.

Comment: really I would like to know which characters @XperianX

Comment: @Sachin just a dot. Check here for more info http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: you can use such characters with double dash. For example for selecting element with id = 'a.b', you can use: $("#a\\.b")

Comment: @Sachin I was aware of that but in my case id was float number and using this 'workaround' worked better than writing function that would insert slashes into every id.

Comment: fair enough @XperianX, apart from that, any statement which takes more than 5 seconds to understand is considered as a bad coding practice. You might want to consider breaking down that statement into multiple lines and statements, it will help other people who might work on this code after you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each level you will need to double the number of slashes plus one before the quote

1. `\"`
2. `\\\"`
3. `\\\\\\\"`
4. `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"`

As you can see with each level you need to put two slashes for each slash and a slash quote for the quote